# Use CodeMirror for standalone syntax highlighting with line numbers

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

I use CodeMirror V. 3 for stand alone syntax highlighting (other parts of my project also uses the CodeMirror editor, so I don't want to use other standalone-syntax highlighting libraries like `google-code-prettify`).

I use the `lib/runmode.js` script as described in the [CodeMirror: Mode Runner Demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/runmode.html) to highlight code in a `<pre>`-tag. This works fine. Now I want to add *line numbers* on the left side of the code just like in the CodeMirror editor.

(The `CodeMirror.runMode` have an `options` argument, but this seems to work only with the tabsize. Any idea how I can add linenumbers to my code (like in google-code-prettify the css-class `linenums`)?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would hack Mode Runner like this

```
  CodeMirror.runMode = function(string, modespec, callback, options) {
  var mode = CodeMirror.getMode(CodeMirror.defaults, modespec);
   var lineNumber = 1; // Line number
   if (callback.nodeType == 1) {
    var tabSize = (options && options.tabSize) || CodeMirror.defaults.tabSize;
    var node = callback, col = 0;
    node.innerHTML = "";
    callback = function(text, style) {


      if (text == "\n") {

      lineNumber++ ; //increment line number
      var lineNum = document.createTextNode(lineNumber); // 

      node.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

      node.appendChild(lineNum); // append
        col = 0;
        return;
      }
      var content = "";
      // replace tabs
      for (var pos = 0;;) {
      var lineNum = document.createTextNode(lineNumber + " ")
        var idx = text.indexOf("\t", pos);
        if (idx == -1) {
          content += text.slice(pos);
          col += text.length - pos;

          break;
        } else {
          col += idx - pos;
          content += text.slice(pos, idx);
          var size = tabSize - col % tabSize;
          col += size;
          for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) content += " ";
          pos = idx + 1;

        }
      }

      if (style) {
        var sp = node.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
        sp.className = "cm-" + style.replace(/ +/g, " cm-");
        sp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
      } else {
        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
      }
    };
  }

  var lines = CodeMirror.splitLines(string), state = CodeMirror.startState(mode);
  for (var i = 0, e = lines.length; i < e; ++i) {
    if (i) callback("\n");
    var stream = new CodeMirror.StringStream(lines[i]);
    while (!stream.eol()) {
      var style = mode.token(stream, state);
      callback(stream.current(), style, i, stream.start);
      stream.start = stream.pos;
    }
  }
// add the first line
 var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
  var firstLine = document.createTextNode("1 ");
  outputDiv.insertBefore(firstLine, outputDiv.firstChild);
};
```

Comment: :-), this works! The line numbers are now directly on the left side, maybe I will improve the script so that they would not be copy&pasted with the normal source text. Thanks for your great help!

Comment: You don't even have to write your own `runMode` -- the existing one takes a callback (as an alternative to the DOM node) that you can use to wire in your own output.